# Laravel 5 input::get error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Why am I having this error? I tried to add use `Illuminate\Http\Request;`
but same error? Also is `$username = $request->input('username');` the same as `$username = Input::get('username');`?

The error I get is:

`FatalErrorException in LoginController.php line 22: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found`

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

  // Display the login form
  public function showLogin()
  {
    return View::make('login');
  }

  // Process submission of the login form by verifying user’s credentials
  public function processLogin()
  {
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    if ($username === 'prince' && $password === 'c@spiAN') {
      return 'Access granted!';
    } else {
      return 'Access denied! Wrong username or password.';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well seems to me, that your not using the `Input` class. I believe there already is a facade in app.php, so on top just add `use Input;`

Comment: I already tried use Input; and having error: class input does not exist.

Comment: Try to search this: `'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,` in app.php in the `aliases` array. If it's not there add it.

Comment: @JonhDoe add slash(\) in the beginning like this: use \Input::get('username');

Comment: Thanks Daan it worked.. Just wondering what is the difference between $username = $request->input('username'); and $username = Input::get('username');?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `use Input;` after `Namespace ...` and then use as `Input::get(..)` or don't add `use` and call `\Input::get(..)`. Find more here: http://php.net/manual/pl/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the namespace, as others told you in the comments.

Imagine it as a capitalized folder structure, now you are under `App\Htt\Controllers`, so it looks for `App\Http\Controllers\Input`.
Anything that is  not directly under the same namespace must be referenced before the class declaration or prefixed with the full namespace adding a backslash `\` at the beginning.

It depends on how many times you need to use it. If just once, then call it using the full path from the root. In this case it would be `\Input` (`\Input::get(...)`), otherwise reference it on the top and call it like you did in the question's code.

To better understand, in case of a model you'd need to call the class `User` as `use App\User;` on the top or directly as `\App\User::all()`(as example) inline in your method's code.